# SublimeVideo Youtube and playlist

Tags: jquery, youtube, playlist, video-player

I use SublimeVideo. I want to use playlist ([playlist](http://test.sublimevideo.net/playlists-autoresize)). Videos in this playlist will be from Youtube ([youtube](http://docs.sublimevideo.net/youtube)).
I use code for youtube and playlist from the documentation together as follow:

```
<div id="playlist1" class="sv_playlist">
<div class="video_wrap">
    <video id="video1" class="sublime" data-youtube-id="10uh__bY1GA" poster="posterframe1.jpg" width="640" height="360" preload="none" data-autoresize="fit">
    </video>
</div>

<ul class="thumbs">
    <li id="thumbnail_video1">
        <a href="">
            <img alt="Thumbnail 1" src="thumbnail1.jpg" />
            <span class="play" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This code show nothing. There is no videoplayer. Videoplayer works perfectly separately for Youtube and playlist, but not together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have already your own loader code for you site, and you did include this code in the pages on your site where the `SublimeVideo` player will be used. The script is highly recommend to be inserted into the `<head>` tag, like following:

```
<head>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.sublimevideo.net/js/ipr592yl.js"></script>
  ...
</head>
```

`ipr592yl` is my token, which is working for local development (127.0.0.1) and for my own deployment site. You should have your own, if not, please let me know and I'm going to guide you through the necessary steps.

To insert a youtube video, all you have to do is to include a `<video>` tag with the correspondent `data-uid` and `data-youtube-id`. They both represent the `YouTube video ID`.

```
<div class='video_wrap'>
  <video id="video1" width="640" height="360" 
         data-uid="UNg9gQsck1c" data-youtube-id="UNg9gQsck1c" preload="none">
  </video>
</div>
```

Have a look at the [**DEMO**](http://sanmarx2.eu5.org/examples/sublimeVideo/playlists-autoresize.html). Here is the code:

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SublimeVideo: Responsive Playlist</title>
    <meta content='text/html;charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/playlist-autoresize.css" media="screen" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sublimevideo.net/js/ipr592yl.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/playlist-autoresize.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="global" style="width:640px; margin:20px auto; padding:0 20px;">
      <h1>SublimeVideo</h1>
      <h3 id='feature-description'>Responsive Playlist with youtube videos</h3>
      <div id="demo">
        <div id="playlist1" class="sv_playlist">
          <div class='video_wrap'>
            <video id="video1" width="640" height="360" data-uid="UNg9gQsck1c" data-youtube-id="UNg9gQsck1c" preload="none">
            </video>
          </div>
          <div class='video_wrap'>
            <video id="video2" class="sublime" width="640" height="360" data-uid="CQeS9Q_oOnY" data-youtube-id="CQeS9Q_oOnY" preload="none">
            </video>
          </div>
          <div class='video_wrap'>
            <video id="video3" class="sublime" width="640" height="360" data-uid="DVwHCGAr_OE" data-youtube-id="DVwHCGAr_OE" preload="none">
            </video>
          </div>

          <ul class='thumbs'>
            <li id='thumbnail_video1'>
              <a href=''>
                <img alt='' src='./images/thumbnail1.png' />
                <span class='play' />
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id='thumbnail_video2'>
              <a href=''>
                <img alt='' src='./images/thumbnail2.png' />
                <span class='play' />
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id='thumbnail_video3'>
              <a href=''>
                <img alt='' src='./images/thumbnail3.png' />
                <span class='play' />
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The jquery (`playlist-autoresize.js`) and css (`playlist-autoresize.css`) are exactly the same used in the [playlist sample](http://test.sublimevideo.net/playlists-autoresize).

Hope it's useful!

Comment: Is there any way to get control of the player using Javascript? When I do `sublime.player('video1').on('metadata', function(player) {
            console.log('Got Metadata' + player.duration());
        });`
I get undefined. Probably because the video is in Youtube <iframe>.